# ¿Como pasar una variable axios a un controlador para que este ejecute una peticion GET?

Tags: laravel, vue.js, axios, get, peticiones

Buenos dias mi duda es como puedo pasar una peticion axios a un controlador en laravel. Mi caso es que presiono una imagen y este desencadena un evento que hace una peticion axios, lo que quiero hacer esque esa peticion axios la mande al controlador y el controlador ejecute una peticion GET al servidor,no tengo mucho conocimiento de laravel pero mi codigo esta asi:

```
<div class="row">
    <a v-on:click="upcam()" href=""><b-img src="/img/flecha.png" fluid alt="Fluid image" style="width: 70px; height: 70px; transform: rotate(270deg); margin-left: 100px"></b-img></a>
</div>
```

y el metodo esta asiya que esta en Vue.js

```
methods:{
        upcam(){ 
            axios.get('AQUI QUIERO CONOCER COMO MANDAR LA URL AL CONTROLADOR')
            .then(function (response) {
                console.log('Send');
            })
            .catch(function (error) {
                console.log('Error');
            });
        },
```

Y este es el controlador que hice :

```
class UpController extends Controller
{
    public function Up(Request $request){
        Http::get('URL QUE QUIERO HACER LA PETICION AL SERVIDOR')->json();
    }
}
```

Comment: ¿Y si agregas la ruta que tienes declarada?

Comment: ¿Con qué fin llamar a una ruta para que esta llame otra ruta?